# Table Sorter download as csv

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to download the filtered content from the sorted table as a csv file. I am picking up the example from [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html).

However when I try the following code nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong here.

```
$("#download").click(function(){
    wo = $("#table1")[0].config.widgetOptions;
    wo.output_separator = ',';
    wo.output_delivery = 'd';
    wo.output_saveRows = 'f';
    wo.output_saveFileName = 'myTable.csv';
    $("#table1").trigger('outputTable');
    return false;
    });
```

table1 is id passed to the table sorter.

EDIT: There are no javascript errors in firebug. The function seems to complete fine but no download happening.

Comment: Have you initiated the plugin?   // call the tablesorter plugin
    $this.find("table").tablesorter({

Comment: Yea, I have initilized it but not with the one that is given in the example, do I need to add the output_seperator, etc in the initilized widgetOptions as well? A quick copy paste did not work though. Also I am not having any dropdown options as given in the example. I just want the table to be downloaded as file on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning

```
$wo = $("#table1").config.widgetOptions;
```

and then using `wo` for further methods. You should use either `wo` or `$wo`.

I added these js files in my code and its working now:

```
 <script src="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
 <script src="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-output.js"></script>
 <script src="http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Remove any other tablesorter js and add the above ones.

Comment: Thanks good catch, but that still did not resolve to problem, still nothing happens on click

Comment: Oh yes, I just noticed it says ` wo = $("#projects").config.widgetOptions;` config undefined. I understand I am doing it a bit differently compared to the example, not too sure if I have got that right. EDIT: I figured out how to get rid of that error. updated in the code. So now no error but no download too

Comment: I am actually trying to accomplish this via Ruby Rails. Would you know were I would need to set it up in that case ?

Comment: are you using any gem for this?

Comment: Yes, gem 'jquery-tablesorter'

Comment: ok it looks like an old gem so you could simply download the above js files put them in you `assets/javscripts` folder.  They would be automatically included if your `application.js` file has this line `//= require_tree`

Comment: Added that, still no response in the download. But I understand widget-output.js wasnt there earlier. Now I have done as mentioned, the js is being loaded in the page but no downloads yet !

Comment: Are all the above js loaded in the sequence as above and after the jquery js. Also are you getting any message on firebug console.

Comment: All js are being loaded, ofcourse i havent removed the gem but new ones are also getting loaded. example: `<script src="/assets/widget-output.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>` Firebug does not show any error. The outputTable trigger is not happening for some reason

Comment: So the moment I remove the gem file the application breaks, saying the theme cant be found. Inspite of having the manually loaded scripts getting loaded. EDIT: I need to look into this, this is a an application specific css file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70553/discussion-between-shobhit-shukla-and-tanvi).